# How to resolve blank errors for Xampp phpMyAdmin and MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

Several problems with phpmyAdmin running on Windows 7 in Xampp.

Creating a new database or editing data within a table, creates a network error message, with the response code being:
{"reload_flag":"1","success":false,"error":""}
Same response code when trying to load the second page of tables, the first page is just loaded again.

When changing a field in the database a blank notification popup is shown:
[Updating a field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m26Rx.png)
Initially MySQL table crashed errors were logged in the event viewer. The error was the 'MySQL table has crashed' and the tables in question were: procs_priv, tables_priv, columns_priv, and db. these errors are no longer being logged, yet we're having the same issues as before.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xampp, re importing the database and then repairing all tables. Non of this had any effect so far.

Answer (score 0):

reload_flag is returned in `auth()` function. It looks like I solved this error by clearing cookies and/or switching between different `auth_type(http, cookie, config)` in `config.inc.php` file